# Wildcard registration in http.sys doesn't match loopback addresses

Tags: http, hosting, owin, netsh, http.sys

I have a service hosted on http://127.0.0.1:2113/ and have made the following URL registration in http.sys

```
http://*:2113/
```

However, for some reason the service throws the exception

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied
HTTP async server failed to start listening
```

If I also add the URL registration

```
http://127.0.0.1:2113/
```

to http.sys, then it works. 
The same scenario unfolds, if I host the service on http://localhost:2113/

Can anyone explain this? I've read about wildcard registrations in http.sys and from what I can understand, it should match these addresses too.
Perhaps I should add, that I've double-checked that I don't have any other registrations on port 2113.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address you register with netsh.exe (http://*:2113/) must exactly match the address you give to HttpListener, that's an http.sys requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found documentation regarding wildcards (both * and +) here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364698(v=vs.85).aspx
But according to your answer, this doesn't apply to http.sys registrations?

Comment: You can use wildcards in your registration, but then you must use the same wildcard when you start HttpListener. The wildcard rules you linked to are about what happens when you have multiple registrations/apps.